# Creating a list from data to include multiple entries then Iterate through list to return one string

Tags: python, python-3.x

**What I have currently**

I want to create a list from this data set to only include the name values, but have them grouped by each 'issue', so I then can iterate through this list and return one value based on priority.

```
{
 "issues": [
    {
      "fields": {
        "components": [],
        "customfield_1": null,
        "customfield_2": null
      }
    },
    {
      "fields": {
        "components": [
            {
              "name": "Testing"
            }
          ],
        "customfield_1": null,
        "customfield_2": null
      }
    },
    {
      "key": "3",
      "fields": {
         "components": [
            {
              "name": "Documentation"
            },
            {
               "name": "Manufacturing"
            }
           ],
          "customfield_1": null,
          "customfield_2": null
      }
     }
  ]
 }
```

I want the output to look something like this:

```
['null', 'testing', ('Documentation', 'Manufacturing')]
```

I was able to accomplish this by the following code:
(sorry about the formatting, not sure how to make this looks better without having it on one line)

```
list((
'null' if len(item['fields']['components'])== 0 
else 
item['fields']['components'][0]['name']) if len(item['fields']['components'])==1 
else 
(item['fields']['components'][0]['name']), item['fields']['components'][1]['name']))) 
for item in data['issues'])
```

**The Problem**

Now I need to have the value `("Documentation", "Manufacturing")` from the above output to return only 1 component based on priority.

I think I need to iterate through something like `['Documentation', 'Testing', 'Manufacturing"]` 
so when it hits, lets say 'Documentation', it stops and returns only 'Documentation'. (this list is specific for priority and is in order of highest to lowest priority)

I want the final list to be `['null', 'Testing', 'Documentation']`

I do not need the others to be changed, just the entry with multiple values.

Comment: Is your example the correct snippet of `json`? I am unable to read it using `json` library

Comment: @hqkhan it's not valid JSON

Comment: Yeah there was some error on it, The edited data should work now

Comment: Now it is valid

Comment: How does priority work in this case? As in, how is it defined? If there are multiple values, you want the first one returned?

Comment: So the list `['Documentation', 'Testing', 'Manufacturing']` is in order of priority, so when the list i return has multiple values for one 'issue' eg. `('Documentation', 'Manufacturing')` it returns with the one with highest priority, in this case it would be "Documentation"

Comment: it was only a suggestion to iterate through a 'priority' list then stop and return one value that the data list shares with the priority list...if that makes sense

Answer (score 1):

How about the code below? I'm basically indexing the priority list and taking the minimum of it (since we're looking at the beginning to be of highest priority). We can switch this to `max` if the priority list ever changes.

Try this:

```
import json

with open("file.json") as f:
   data = json.load(f)

result = []
priority = ['Documentation', 'Testing', 'Manufacturing']

for issue_dict in data['issues']:
    if len(issue_dict["fields"]["components"]) == 0:
        result.append([('null', 0)])
    else: # Can support arbitrary number of custom fields
        result.append([(list(name_dict.values())[0], priority.index(list(name_dict.values())[0]))  for name_dict in issue_dict["fields"]["components"]])

print(result)
# [[('null', 0)], [('Testing', 1)], [('Documentation', 0), ('Manufacturing', 2)]]

result = [min(item, key= lambda x: x[1])[0] for item in result]

print(result)
#['null', 'Testing', 'Documentation']
```

For the nested lists: if the length is 1, then `min` will simply take the only choice obviously. For the others, we find the minimum index aka highest priority.

I've included some print statements strictly for debugging and for you to see if it makes sense. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

So i ended up doing it this way:

creating a function that will look if any "components" are in the given list, and will return and stop the iteration when the given component is found

```
def _define_component(multiple_component_list):

        for components in ['Documentation', 'Testing', 'Manufacturing']:
            if components in multiple_component_list:
                return components

        return 'Unknown'
```

and calling the function in my list comprehension with the expression i used when the length > 1 as the argument (same as original code except after the last 'else' statement)

```
list(('Unknown' if len(item['fields']['components']) == 0 else
                           item['fields']['components'][0]['name'] if len(
                           item['fields']['components']) == 1 else _define_component(
                           [item['fields']['components'][0]['name'],
                            item['fields']['components'][1]['name']]))for item in data['issues'])
```

Comment: That's great if it works. Just a word of advice, you should try your best to make your code readable. This of course depends on who will look at the code and its actual purpose but having a really long one liner is usually undesirable.

Comment: Yeah i understand, the list comprehension part is a lot bigger in my actual code and isn't to create a list of just components......its for inserting values into a database so the list that it returns is (components[0], value1[0], value2[0]), (components[1], value1[1], value2[1]) ect.